# find the maximum nchar for each row in a data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 200 columns. I would like to find the maximum value of nchar across column 6 to the last column for each row.

```
CHROM   POS REF RANK    HETERO_COUNT    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
Chr20   84  C   Rank4   12  C/C C/C C/A C/C C/C
Chr20   102 TAA Rank4   8   TAA/TAA TAA/TAA TAA/TA  TAA/TAA TA/TA
Chr20   104 ACCCCC  Rank3   21  ACCCCC/ACCCCCC  ACCCCCC/ACCCCCC ACCCCC/ACCCCC   ACCCCC/ACCCCC   ACCCCC/ACCCCC
Chr20   109 C   Rank4   67  C/T C/T -/- C/T C/C
Chr20   118 A   Rank4   16  A/A C/C A/C A/A A/A
```

I expect to add a column containing the maximum of nchar values for each row.

```
CHROM   POS REF RANK    HETERO_COUNT    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 max
Chr20   84  C   Rank4   12  C/C C/C C/A C/C C/C 3
Chr20   102 TAA Rank4   8   TAA/TAA TAA/TAA TAA/TA  TAA/TAA TA/TA   7
Chr20   104 ACCCCC  Rank3   21  ACCCCC/ACCCCCC  ACCCCCC/ACCCCCC ACCCCC/ACCCCC   ACCCCC/ACCCCC   ACCCCC/ACCCCC   15
Chr20   109 C   Rank4   67  C/T C/T -/- C/T C/C 3
Chr20   118 A   Rank4   16  A/A C/C A/C A/A A/A 3
```

Thank you for any helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
df1$max <- apply(df1[6:ncol(df1)], 1, function(x) max(nchar(x)))
```

or

```
do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(nchar(as.matrix(df1[6:ncol(df1)]))))
```

or as commented by @BrodieG, `max.col` can be used as well

```
 chars <- nchar(as.matrix(df1[-(1:5)]))
 chars[cbind(1:nrow(chars), max.col(chars))]
```

Comment: or `{chars <- nchar(as.matrix(df[-(1:5)])); chars[cbind(1:nrow(chars), max.col(chars))]}` (+1)